# Why i can not paste environment variables in inteelij-idea?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, environment-variables

[image]

I am trying to paste my environment variable (`NAME=asif;HOME=false;`) here, but there is no right-click option and `ctr+v` is not working. To add variables i have to click the three dots and enter variables one by one. How to add my variables by just `ctr+v` ?

Comment: Update to the new version this will resolve

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest IntelliJ IDEA version of:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Ultimate Edition) 
Build #IU-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020
```

Copy-pasting environment variables separated with `;` works for me:

[image]

I guess they changed this and so it's worth updating if you want this feature